# why is the runtime 0 when using map in python

Tags: python, dictionary

when I use the **map** function, the runtime is 0. but when I do the same operation using **FOR**, it displays the time taken for the script to run.

```
def forthpower(n):

    return n*n*n*n

t2 = time.time()
xx = map(forthpower, range(10000000))
print("The process took {:1.10f}".format(time.time()-t2))
```

*output: The process took 0.0000000000*

```
def forthpower(n):

    return n*n*n*n

t2 = time.time()
xx = []
for x in range(10000000):
    xx.append(forthpower(x))

print("The process took {:1.10f}".format(time.time()-t2))
```

*output: The process took 10.5718030930*

Comment: `map()` is an iterator, it only processes data on request. You do not iterate over if or take any item from it.

Comment: @KlausD. mmm can you cordially explain it a little bit more? what do you mean by "take any item from it"?

Comment: `map` didn’t do anything yet. It just returns an *iterator*. If and when you iterate over that (e.g. `for..in`), each item will be processed if and when needed.

Comment: @deceze oh now i got it. it totally makes sense because when i add   "print(len(list(xx)))", the runtime is not zero.  thank you so muchhh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Klaus D. said, map() is an iterator, it will process data only when requested.

If you add:

```
print(list(xx))
```

you'll start seing a difference.